# Проблема с SlideToggle когда используем load

Tags: jquery, html5

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".menu ul").slideToggle();
  });
  /*Подгрузка на другую страницу*/
  $(".test").load("index.html .menu")
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <button>Menu</button>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

У нас есть две страницы: *index.html* и *page.html*. Когда мы находимся на странице *index.html*, нажимаем на кнопку и меню работает на ура! Когда мы находимся на *page.html* мы делаем подгрузку `$(".test").load("index.html .menu")` в блок текста меню, то `slideToggle()` не работает! В чем проблема?

Comment: У вас не рабочий пример.  `$(".test")` - где этот элемент? Его нет.  `load("index.html .menu")` - это файл или селектор у вас в кавычках? Не может быть чтобы оба одновременно

Comment: у меня нету второй страницы где есть див  test, туда идет подгрузка из файла index , а блок меню подгр.

Comment: Вы хотите загрузить часть файла `index.html`? А с чего вы решили, что это возможно? И самое главное, где вы нашли, что это должно так работать: `load("index.html .menu")`?

Comment: Так у меня все работает !Тоесть меню из index.html загружаеться на страницу page.html , но не работает slideToggle()

Comment: Да. действительно, упустил такой функционал, извините

Comment: Но почему slideToggle() не работает не могу понять!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Поскольку элемент заменяется другим, то обработчики события пропадают.**

Попробуйте следующее, вместо того чтобы назначать на сам элемент:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "button", function() {
  //здесь ваш код 
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", "button", function() {
    $(".menu ul").slideToggle();
  });
  /*Подгрузка на другую страницу*/
  $(".test").load("index.html .menu")
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <button>Menu</button>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

или установите обработчик события после загрузки меню:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*Подгрузка на другую страницу*/
  $(".test").load("index.html .menu", function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() {
      $(".menu ul").slideToggle();
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <button>Menu</button>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Page</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо 1 вариант сработал!

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers